# Not sure why I'm getting this C# error

Tags: c#, sql, umbraco7

The error is: `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

I have no idea why this is happening, please bare in mind that I'm very new to C# and don't exactly understand how to work with it yet. I'm trying to get the file to retrieve a column from a database table and insert it into a CSV file with extra headers.
The database table is cmsDictionary and the column is key, this should populate the CSV key column and the others should be blank to be populated by the user which will then be imported into the cmsLanguageText table.

```
//This is my controller file which is throwing the error.

using UmbracoImportExportPlugin.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using Umbraco.Core.Persistence;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace UmbracoImportExportPlugin.App_Code
{
    public class ExportDictionaryAllController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
    {

        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public static void ExportAll(List<Item> DictionaryItems)
        {
            getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems);
            string attachment = "attachment; filename= DictionaryItems.csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            WriteColumnName();
            foreach (Item item in DictionaryItems)
            {
                WriteItemInfo(item);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        private static void WriteItemInfo(Item item)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            AddComma(item.Key, sb);
            AddComma(item.English, sb);
            AddComma(item.Hebrew, sb);
            AddComma(item.Russian, sb);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private static void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Append(value.Replace(',', ' '));
            sb.Append(", ");
        }

        private static void WriteColumnName()
        {
            string columnNames = "Key, English, Hebrew, Russian";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public List<String> getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems)
        {
            UmbracoDatabase db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
            var select = new Sql("SELECT key FROM cmsDictionary");
            List<Item> DictionaryItems = db.Fetch<Item>(select);
            return DictionaryItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: @janhartmann I doubt it! See `getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems);` for example!

Comment: It doesn't compile, it's a compilation error. however when I change `getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems);` to `getList(DictionaryItems);` I receive the following error: **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'UmbracoImportExportPlugin.App_Code.ExportDictionaryAllController.getList(System.Collections.Generic.List<UmbracoImportExportPlugin.Models.Item>)**

Comment: That's because you are trying to call a non static method inside a static method. Either make a new instance of the class or mark the getList method as static. Also you're not using the return value.

Comment: I don't understand what people mean by the return value, can somebody tell me what I have to return, and if I have to return it in `getList()` or whether I have to return it in `ExportAll()`?

Comment: 1    do not use [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")] GET and POST on same method, better to make different http methods for different verbs.

2     getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems) method is not static so u cant call it from static method here

3-    getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems); should be called like getList(DictionaryItems);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this line seems wrong:

```
getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems);
```

Should be:

```
getList(DictionaryItems);
```

The compiler error should give you a line in the code file where the error is.

Comment: also, return value is not used.

Comment: What do you mean by return value is not used? I have `return DictionaryItems;`

Comment: He means in the code that calls this method, you don´t use the return-value (consider not the param is changed as it is called by value, not by reference)

Comment: And getList is not a static method, so it still won't complie.. =/

Comment: so I've made `getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems)` static. but now I receive this error: **CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiControllerBase.ApplicationContext.get'**

Comment: Why are these methods all static - there seems to be no need.

Comment: @Paddy I removed static from all of them now and changed the way I called DictionaryItems in the ExportAll method and now it seems not to be giving me any errors.

Answer (score -1):

Use this as your method definition:

```
public static List<String> getList(List<Item> DictionaryItems) 
{ 
  UmbracoDatabase db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database; 
  var select = new Sql("SELECT key FROM cmsDictionary"); 
  List<string> DictionaryItems = db.Fetch<Item>(select); 
  return DictionaryItems; 
}
```